# How to search control in TemplatedColumn WebDataGrid InitializeRow event?

Tags: infragistics, webdatagrid

I want to search for the dropdownlist object which is in TemplatedColumn. I assume that I would be able to find it as we do in GridView or ListView templated controls.

e.Row.Cells is not available WebDataGrid control's InitializeRow event. I am using latest downloads from Infragistics. I am not using UltraWebGrid.. UI think it was avaiable in old version of control suit .. correct me if I am wrong

I would really appreciate if you could help... !!

Thank You !! - Nilesh

Answer (score 2):

When you have a reference to the GridRecordItem, call FindControl on it to find children in the template.  The GridRecordItem is exposed by the Items collection of The GridRecord which is what e.Row exposes in the InitializeRow event.

If you are defining your templates in code, then you could do what you need in the InstantiateIn method.  There are examples creating templates in code in the NetAdvantage help:
http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/Current/CLR4.0/?page=WebDataGrid_Refrence_a_Cell_When_Creating_an_Item_Template.html